# Detect current screen bounds

Tags: java, swing, awt, screen, mousemotionevent

I am working on an application that has `setDecoration(false)` and I have a `MouseMotionlistener` so I can move it around, and at the moment I am trying to make a maximize button. On the default monitor it works perfectly, but on a second monitor if I click the maximize button it will maximize to the default screen. How would I get the X & Y coordinates of the screen the application is currently on?

I.E. I have 2 monitors both at 1600x900, so if the application is on monitor 1, the X & Y would be 0 & 0, but if it is one the second monitor it would be 1600 & 0.

But I need it so it works on all sized monitors i.e. 1200x800, or if the monitors are positioned vertical instead of horizontal.

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends on the definition of screen.  Do you want the default screen bounds or a specific screen bounds?

I use the following (& variations of it) to determine the screen bounds for an individual screen

```
public static GraphicsDevice getGraphicsDeviceAt(Point pos) {
    GraphicsDevice device = null;
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice lstGDs[] = ge.getScreenDevices();
    ArrayList<GraphicsDevice> lstDevices = new ArrayList<GraphicsDevice>(lstGDs.length);

    for (GraphicsDevice gd : lstGDs) {
        GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
        Rectangle screenBounds = gc.getBounds();
        if (screenBounds.contains(pos)) {
            lstDevices.add(gd);
        }
    }

    if (lstDevices.size() == 1) {
        device = lstDevices.get(0);
    }
    return device;
}

public static Rectangle getScreenBoundsAt(Point pos) {
    GraphicsDevice gd = getGraphicsDeviceAt(pos);
    Rectangle bounds = null;

    if (gd != null) {
        bounds = gd.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
    }
    return bounds;
}
```

The basic idea is to provide a screen location and find the screen that matches it.  I have variations the take a `Component` or `Window` but essentially, it boils down to this.

From a `MouseEvent`, you can obtain the screen coordinates simply enough with a call to [MouseEvent.getLocationOnScreen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getLocationOnScreen%28%29)

Now, from your question, it sounds like you want to know the entire "virtual" screen bounds (I might be wrong), but I use this method (actually I use it to create multi-monitor wallpapers on the fly, but that's another question)

```
public static Rectangle getVirtualScreenBounds() {
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice lstGDs[] = ge.getScreenDevices();

    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle();
    for (GraphicsDevice gd : lstGDs) {
        bounds.add(gd.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds());
    }
    return bounds;
}
```

Basically, it just walks all the screen devices and add's there regions together to form a "virtual" rectangle.  You could use the same concept to return the bounds of each screen device as an array instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to get the screen dimensions.

```
Toolkit toolkit =  Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ();
Dimension dim = toolkit.getScreenSize();
System.out.println("Width of Screen Size is "+dim.width+" pixels");
System.out.println("Height of Screen Size is "+dim.height+" pixels");
```

Comment: This will return the "default" screen bounds only

Comment: The main thing I'm after is getting the top, left co-ords of the screen the app is currently on, so from my setup it would either be 0, 0 or 1600, 0, as I have 2 monitors side by side at 1600x900, but if I had my monitors one on top of the other the top, left would be 0, 0 or 0, 900, do you see where I'm going with this?...