# Fetching coordinates for top left position of top left monitor

Tags: java, swing, awt, multiple-monitors

I am trying to fetch the coordinates of the top left position in a multimonitor setup for my screen capture program. Here is what I've currently got for the program:

```
        int dwidth = 0, dheight = 0; //max dimensions of all monitors
    for (GraphicsDevice gd : GraphicsEnvironment
            .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()) {
        if (gd == GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
                .getDefaultScreenDevice()) {
            minx = -width; //My attempt at finding the minimum X value did not work
        }
        dwidth += gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
        dheight += gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight();
    }
```

Basically I want to be able to run my program across all of the monitors. For full code view here: https://gist.github.com/fletchto99/5788659

Comment: somebody told me that swing can't handle multiple monitors.

Comment: @JensSchauder My program works in my dual screen setup, but not my friends triple screen setup.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714215/detect-current-screen-bounds/11714302#11714302). It discusses how to to calculate the virtual bounds of the desktop, but it does so but listing concaternating the screen bounds of each screen

Comment: @MattLanglois Don't forget, an up vote is always appreciated ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Is there a way I can make the comment my accepted answer? -- I don't use this site too often. If you want to answer it with the same thing, I can accept that so others can see.

Comment: @MattLanglois I create an answer which more directly answers your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of `GraphicDevice`s from the `GraphicsEnvironment`.  Each `GraphicsDevice` would represent a screen.

Now, you have a number of choices...

You could simply look through the list of `GraphicsDevices` and simply find the one with the lowest x/y coordinates or you could combine them all into a "virtual screen" and simply extract the top/left coordinates from it.

For example...

```
public static Rectangle getVirtualScreenBounds() {

    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice lstGDs[] = ge.getScreenDevices();

    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle();
    for (GraphicsDevice gd : lstGDs) {

        bounds.add(gd.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds());

    }

    return bounds;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, the coordinate system in the graphic libraries starts at the top-left part of the screen. So your code should always be equivalent to simply stating: `0, 0`.

Comment: This bring up the top left corner for the main monitor, I'm trying to put the window to the top left corner of the top left monitor. I've already tried this, but if the left monitor isn't the main one then the coordinates can be negative. For example this setup here: http://gyazo.com/82bded44baa10fd347c93fa7804f6347.png

Comment: Not true. The screens can appear at < 0 and are based on the position relative to the default/master screen