# How do I determine the resolution of the screen where the JFrame resides?

Tags: java, swing, screen, resolution

I wish to determine the screen resolution where my java application is currently showing.

For example, lets say a user has my java application on his second monitor and the two monitors have the specifications of: primary 1024x1280 (Portrait rotation), secondary 1280x1024 (Landscape rotation).

I want to make the height of my popup JList fit within a comfortable margin of the second monitor. I won't get the correct results from Toolkit#getDefaultToolkit()#getScreenSize() as this would give me the dimensions from the primary monitor.

I could get the size of all the monitors by using GraphicsEnvironment#getScreenDevices() but **how do I figure out which of these devices my JFrame is running within**?

Thanks for your time.

-Dennis

Comment: Take the Rectangle bounds of the frame and determine if it fits inside the Rectangle bounds of any of the GraphicsDevices. For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714215/detect-current-screen-bounds/11714302#11714302)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `frame` is your `JFrame`, you can simply use the following code to retrieve the `GraphicsDevice`:

```
frame.getGraphicsConfiguration().getDevice();
```

From there, you can get the whole the information of the screen on which the frame is displayed.

Answer (score 2):

check out this link . the answer is already explained here. ( The accepted answer )
[Java Toolkit Getting Second screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322627/java-toolkit-getting-second-screen-size)

> you can get from a JFrame to its device via the getGraphicsConfigration() method, which returns a GraphicsConfiguration that has a getDevice()

Comment: Thank you. I missed that during my search.