# Customize the output of a monitor

Tags: java, ubuntu, graphics, monitor

I am creating a program using Java. Within this program I would like to have the ability to create a certain output on a predefined monitor. My Ubuntu 14.10 test system has 2 monitors connected through DVI. Unity grabs both monitors for its desktop. How would I access these monitors? Is there any way to create a connection through /dev/*? Or do I have to do that in my Java program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GraphicsEnvironment`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html) to get a list of the [`GraphicsDevices`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html) attached to your system.

If you want to, you can generate a "virtual" desktop, combining all the devices areas together, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714215/detect-current-screen-bounds/11714302#11714302)